# Grouping in my SQL for a constraint less than 10

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused on which table I should use and or should I `join` the tables when attempting this question?

> List total number of hotels in the database that have less than 10 rooms.
>
> Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
>
> Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
>    Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
>
> Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)

I have tried by just useing one table `Room` in my statement

```
SELECT hotelNo 
FROM Room
WHERE roomNo < 10
GROUP BY hotelNo;
```

Would this be correct or should I use something like this?

```
SELECT h.hotelNo,r.roomNo 
FROM Hotel h JOIN Room r ON h.hotelNo= r.hotelNo
WHERE r.roomNo < 10
GROUP BY hotelNo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all hotels have at least one room, you don't need a join.  But, you do need aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select r.hotelno
      from rooms r
      group by r.hotelno
      having count(*) < 10
     ) r;
```

The subquery returns the hotels that have fewer than 10 rooms (and are in the `rooms` table, so they have at least one room).

The outer query counts the number of such hotels.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff: What does the `r` do at the end of the query and also the Count (*) there are other tab. How doe this know just to count the hotels? There are other tables in the data base I have edited my question to show them

Comment: @Liam . . . The `r` is a table alias.  As I explain in the answer, the inner query lists the hotels that meet your criterion.  The outer query counts the number of rows in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Check count on the having in order to be applied to the groups, and that count the number of rows returned by that query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT hotelRo
    FROM Room
    GROUP BY hotelNo
    HAVING COUNT(*)<10
) AS TMP;
```

Comment: Could you do this just using the Room table? Or would this be incorrect

Comment: you mean using just one query? i think you can't because if you do select count(*) in the subquery, it will return the size for each group instead of the whole set